# Add www. to Drupal 7 canonical tag using Metatags module

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, canonical-link

I am currently using the metatags module in Drupal 7 to set the canonical tags, however the canonical URL that it shows on the live page does not have a www. in it.

This is an issue because the I have set Drupal to rewrite the URLs so that they all have www. at the beginning of the URL

For example, the current canonical URL is **http://example.com** whereas I would like it to be **http://www.example.com**

Currently in the metatags module the pages are set to use `[current-page:url:absolute]`    as the canonical.

Answer (score 0):

I have just figured it out. I changed the `$base_url` variable in **/sites/default/settings.php** to include the www. in the URL and this solved the issue.